# I am 1.7 m tall and bought a MTB with a frame that is 3-5 cm too big

Tags: frames, size

The frame is 5 cm too big for me (in the length from seat to handles). I have major discomfort in my shoulders. After getting a shorter stem, the shoulders are 95% improved, but the "jewels" go dead after ~25 km.

Is this still the size issue or what else can I play around with?

Comment: What is the bike brand and model and specified size of the frame?

Comment: How old are you?  Are you finished growing?  Our advice for someone under 18 would be different to someone over 25.

Comment: Have you played with the seat angle? Lower the nose a fraction and see if it helps (Watch you don;t go too much, which will have you fighting against sliding forward).

Comment: A different (narrower perhaps) saddle might also help

Comment: If you've finished growing, you might consider trading-in the bike for one that is fitting. And take it for a lesson to try-out before buying.

Answer (score 3):

A bike with too much 'reach' i.e., the bars are to far forward and low would only affect seat comfort if you are not able to band your spine enough and are having to rotate your pelvis forward as well.

I'd check your seat height, fore-aft position and tilt for proper adjustment first. There are many guides for seat height and fore-aft position available online. For for-aft position look up the 'knee over pedal spindle' (KOPS) method which will give you a good approximate seat position.

Note that moving the seat forward to be more upright in your upper body also moves your feet relatively further back which can rotate your pelvis forward and exacerbate the discomfort you are experiencing.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do is have a frame that fits your body.  Save for that, any modification is going to be a trade off in one way or the other.

Since you are talking about top-tube length, I am assuming the stand over height is okay for you.  Fitting a bike for a person with a long or short torso can be difficult (I should know, I am 6'0" with a 30" inseam so I tend to either have too short of a distance between seat and bars, or have issues with stand over clearance.

If you are willing to make the sacrafices, there are a couple things you can do.  First, make sure your seat is positioned as far forward as possible.  The other thing you can do is continue to play around with the stem and/or bars.  A shorter stem is going to help, but you may also want to try a higher stem angle, or even an adjustable stem.  I know Giant makes a stem that is adjustable from -10 to +50 degrees.  You might look funny with such an upright stem, but apart from getting a different frame, it might work for you.

Remember that moving your seat forward and arms in/up are going to affect the balance of the bike, and perhaps also your pedaling stroke.

If the fit is bearable, but you are still dealing with "numb junk" you can try tipping your seat forward.  It may feel akward at first, but it can also improve pressure issues.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Or a saddle with a central cut-out might help.